# Trigger a build in teamcity build server from visual svn

Tags: teamcity, visualsvn-server

Is there a way to notify teamcity when ever someone does a commit to a repository on visual svn?  This is so every time someone commits to the repository a build in teamcity will trigger immediately without the developer having to wait for polling to kick in on its set time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something using Subversion hooks to achieve that, but is it really worthwhile? You could set your TeamCity server to poll every 10 seconds, which is nothing in terms of a performance hit to the SVN repository and probably nothing much in terms of the wait for developers. (I mean, how long does your build take?)

Comment: I know that the post commit hook would work but that required the build url which I don't know how to find.  What would happen if we had say 50 projects all polling every 10 seconds and seeing as the polling  time setting is for the entire server how much would it hurt performance?  And what about projects that we aren't really working on or haven't touched in a while. We don't want it to keep polling those projects if it doesn't have to.

Comment: You can adjust the poll time per project (at least on EAP 6, only one I have used).  We have polls of around 3 minutes to reduce overhead.